# python : read-write lock with writers preference

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Can you suggest me read-write lock in python with writers preference ? I googled online for this and there seems of lot of code but I am not sure they are tested properly .

Please suggest me if you have personally used read-write lock in python and had no issues with it.